# Which of these Matlab built-in Poisson pmf is most accurate?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

In Matlab we may have at least three methods to compute Poisson pmf.

My question is which one of the following provides the most accurate answer:

```
clear all
close all

pd = makedist('Poisson','lambda',5);
[ poisspdf(15,5)  pdf(pd,15) exp(-5)*5^15/factorial(15)] % comparison
```

ans =

1.0e-03 *

0.157245434321078   0.157245434321078   0.157245434321077

Comment: I'm going to guess that is definitely not the last one. What result did you get? Are the first two not identical in some way?

Comment: Last two are identical. 
ans =
   0.001935788121926   0.000157245434321   0.000157245434321

Comment: Add that to your answer

Comment: I'd go with the first one then. You can tell just from looking that the last one is losing precision like crazy. All the numbers in the numerator and denominator are enormous. The first version likely has a lookup table or similar, which I would expect to give much more accurate results. But that's just educated guessing on my part.

Comment: `pdf` internally just calls `poisspdf`. So they give exactly the same results, with `poisspdf` being a little faster. Note that you have the two arguments reversed, it should be `poisspdf(15,5)`. Avoid the `factorial` version at all costs, for the reason @MadPhysicist explained

Comment: @LuisMendo Thank you for highlighting the syntax error.